# Ignite cluster size using control script

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I need to get ignite cluster size(no of server nodes running) preferably using control script or ignite rest api. I am able to get baseline nodes using command below but I don't see any command or rest api to return topology snapshot. Is there a way we could get this information to ignite client rather than looking into logs.

Workaround to get baseline nodes:

```
baselineNodes=$(kubectl --kubeconfig  config.conf exec <ignite-node> -n {client_name} -- /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/bin/./control.sh --baseline | grep "Number of baseline nodes" | cut -d ':' -f2 | sed 's/^ *//g')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help from ignite community and below command worked for me. Basically idea is to use metric to extract server nodes.

```
kubectl --kubeconfig  config.conf exec <ignite-node> -n {client_name} -- /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/bin/./control.sh --metric  cluster.TotalServerNodes | grep -v  "metric" | grep cluster.TotalServerNodes | cut -d " " -f5 | sed 's/^ *//g'
```

Quoting the reply received:

"You can query any metric value or system view content via control script [1], [2]

> control.sh --system-view nodes

or [3]

> control.sh —metric cluster.TotalBaselineNodes
> control.sh —metric cluster.TotalServerNodes
> control.sh —metric cluster.TotalClientNodes

[1] https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/control-script#metric-command
[2] https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/control-script#system-view-command
[3] [https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/monitoring-metrics/new-metrics#cluster"](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/monitoring-metrics/new-metrics#cluster%22)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `topology` REST command could do the trick. Here's the documentation [link](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/restapi#topology).

`http://host:port/ignite?cmd=top&attr=true&mtr=true&id=c981d2a1-878b-4c67-96f6-70f93a4cd241`

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I hope you mean below command,  I will try this.
http://host:port/ignite?cmd=log&from={from}&to={to}&path={pathToLogFile}

Comment: no, this one `http://host:port/ignite?cmd=top&attr=true&mtr=true&id=c981d2a1-878b-4c67-96f6-70f93a4cd241`

Comment: something is wrong with the anchors on the page

Comment: Umm, I have 2 queries. 
1. client need to know the node id to use
2. response doesn't contain the cluster topology but node level metrics and caches.

I was looking for something like below

servers=3, clients=2, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=40, offheap=15.0GB, heap=12.0GB